# Grails: Does the addTo() method not work on newly created objects?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.5.5, and I have a simple scenario here: A has many Bs.

And so I have a transactional service method which basically does the following:.

```
A a 
if (isNew) {
    a = new A()
} else {
    a = A.findById(someId)
} 

List<B> bList = getBsFromSomeOtherMethod() 
bList.each { a.addToBs(it) } 

a.save(failOnError: true)
```

The interesting thing is that if I create a new object (as in, isNew is true in the above logic), then I get the following exception when save() is called: `reassociated object has dirty collection reference (or an array)`.

However, if I get an object which already exists in the DB, then everything works perfectly.

The workaround I found is that if I save the new object before adding Bs to A, then things work. But I would rather not have to call save() twice, and the code is just a lot cleaner if the call was just at the end.

I've googled the exception but nothing seems to explain what's going on here.
Can somebody help out with this?

Comment: The issue is that `A` needs to have an ID associated with it for the queries that are issued for adding `B`s to it. You can't avoid calling `.save()` on the `A` if you create a new one first in order to get this to work. Just add `if (isNew) a.save()` before you add any `B`s to it. One line of code doesn't make it a lot less cleaner.

Comment: You need to save the created object before associating it to the b object list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like others have said in the comments, you need to save the object so it exists in the database, and has an id. When you have a `A has many Bs` relationship, a new table in the database (something like `a_b`) is created to map `A.id` to `B.id`, which is why you can't add `B`s to `A` without saving first.

```
A a 
if (isNew) {
    a = new A()
    a.save()
} else {
    a = A.findById(someId)
} 

List<B> bList = getBsFromSomeOtherMethod() 
bList.each { a.addToBs(it) } 

a.save(failOnError: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [findOrSaveBy](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/findOrSaveBy.html) for such an operations. You will get the proper object from db or persist new one:

```
def a = A.findOrSaveByField(field)
List<B> bList = getBsFromSomeOtherMethod() 
bList.each { a.addToBs(it) }
a.save(failOnError: true)
```